# Sound too low in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, msi, sound-blaster

I had bought some new components for my PC. The fact is when I try to play any sound it's almost audible, the sound is very low, even at max level. This is not a hardware problem, because when I'm on Windows, sound works properly.
My specs are:
-MSI Gaming 5 motherboard.
-Intel Core i5 4570
-8GB Ram
-Nvidia GeForce 465 GTX
Thanks in advance.
P.S.: I think motherboard uses some kind of hardware to improve quality of sound. Something like Audio Boost, which uses Creative Sound-Blaster or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, check volume in every tabs in the "sound parameters" applet.
Then install and launch "pavucontrol"  (pulse audio volume control), check "output devices " tab, scroll down as your main soundcard may be the last one, increase volume on its fader. Also check "configuration" tab and try other profiles.

If not better, for additional settings, you can check volume  in "alsamixer" running it in a terminal or more easily installing "**gnome-alsamixer**" from software center:
Run gnome-alsamixer from launcher, choose the main soundcard from the tabs  (probably you  don't need HDMI soundcard , select the other), check volume and mute state.

If not ok, you can run alsainfo, by copying the following command line in a terminal , choose upload and post the result url:

`wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`

Comment: Everything in the sound applet is at maximum level. It might sound a little weird, but, every time I restart the computer, sound level changes alone, but with the same configuration in the Control Panel. I'm using right now paman to get information.

Comment: I saw a strange behavior in applet control. When I change the sound device (integrated sound card has speakers and headphones options) I want to use, the system silences itself, then I raise all levels to 100%. P.S.: I'm only using headphones. The results of alsainfo are there: http://pastebin.com/fTw3b575

Comment: Are the volumes ok when you set to 100% ? you can increase level to more than 100 % (amplify) in the normal sound settings clicking "enable over 100%"

Comment: Yes, I can, but it sounds very distorted.I think I can try changing the kernel I have. I think I'm going to have a look to SteamOS (on MSI webpage it's said that the motherboard is prepared to work with). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now , all your volumes faders are 100% (or more if amplified ) , so  lower then around 75 %. kernel change is not needed (except if part of  normal upgrade of course)

Comment: From what I read yesterday, there was a bug in Realtek ACL1150 driver that was solved in kernel 3.15rc6, but I don't know if the fix was backported to Ubuntu. Anyway, I'm going to try reinstalling Ubuntu, or something like that. Maybe there was a problem during the setup.